# Split character from string in Idiomatic way Kotlin

Tags: kotlin

Hey I am working in kotlin. I have one string in which I want to split into list from there where I should provide character. I'll explain in details

**For example 1**

```
val string = "Birth Control"

val searchText = "n"
```

**Output**

```
["Birth Co", "trol"]
```

**For example 2**

```
val string = "Bladder Infection"
    
val searchText = "i"
```

**Actual Output**

```
["Bladder ", "nfect", "on"]
```

**Expect Output**

```
["Bladder ", "nfection"]
```

I tried some code but `example 1` is working fine but `example 2` is not because I only want to split first occurrence.

```
val splitList = title?.split(searchText, ignoreCase = true)?.toMutableList()
splitList?.remove(searchText)
```

Can someone guide me how to solve this idiomatic way. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure your expected output ["Bladder ", "nfect", "ion"] is what you want? The first 'i' splits the list and is dropped, the second also splits the list, but is not dropped from the result?

Comment: Sorry I updated my `expected output`

Comment: @lukas.j I need this output `["Bladder ", "nfection"]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You miss the *limit* option of the split function. If you give it a value of 2 the result list will have a maximum of 2 entries:

```
val result = "Bladder Infection".split("i", ignoreCase = true, limit = 2)
```